# Contract "CommitteePrecompiled" should be marked as abstract

Tags: compilation, solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract CommitteePrecompiled{
    function RegisterNode() public;                                     
    function QueryState()   public view returns(string memory, int );  
    function QueryGlobalModel()  public view returns(string memory, int );   
    function UploadLocalUpdate(string memory, int256 )  public;  
    function UploadScores(int256 , string memory)   public; 
    function QueryAllUpdates()  public view returns(string memory); 
}
```

when i try to compile CommitteePrecompiled.sol,'Contract "CommitteePrecompiled" should be marked as abstract.' comes out,how can i fix this bug?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

abstract contract CommitteePrecompiled{
    function RegisterNode() virtual public;                                     
    function QueryState()   virtual public view returns(string memory, int );  
    function QueryGlobalModel()  virtual public view returns(string memory, int );   
    function UploadLocalUpdate(string memory, int256 )  virtual public;  
    function UploadScores(int256 , string memory)   virtual public; 
    function QueryAllUpdates()  
}
```

when i modify like above,it compiles successfully.But file CommitteePrecompiled.bin contains none.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other OOP languages, a Solidity contract/class becomes abstract when some of its functions are not implemented. In other words, they're **missing the function bodies**.

If you want to make the contract non-abstract, you need to implement all of its functions.

For example:

```
contract CommitteePrecompiled {
    struct Node {
        // TODO params
    }
    mapping (address => Node[]) userNodes;

    function RegisterNode() public {
        Node memory node = Node(/* TODO params */);
        userNodes[msg.sender].push(node);
    }

    function QueryState()   public view returns(string memory, int ) {
        // TODO your code to retrieve the state and return a `string` and an `int`
    }

    // TODO implement all your functions
}
```